# Trying to Identify the non repeating values from the console and print the non-repeating values to output

Tags: java

I am trying to print the non repeated values when user enter some numbers it should display the numbers which are not duplicate. i am getting all the values and my program is as below

```
public class Compare {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the string:");
            int[] array = new int[7];
            for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
         } 
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                boolean found = false;
                for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++)
                    if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                        found = true;
                      break;
                    }
               if(!found)
                System.out.println(array[i]);
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: you can use `Set` to store integers and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `boolean found`, take a `int count=0` for counting the numbers and print the numbers which have `count == 1`

Change the code accordingly as shown

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count=0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
                if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
           if(count==1)
            System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Input:
1
2
2
3
3
4
5

Output:
1
4
5

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change two things:

1. Check the whole array for duplicates. `int j = 0` instead of `int j = i`
2. Don't compare the the value with itself. Add `&& i != j` to your if condition.

Now your code will work.

Input: 1,2,3,3,4,5,6

Output: 1,2,4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

How about using, [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)?

It will only contain non duplicate values.

Comment: if he input 3 and 3 the hashset stores a 3. but he dont want to output one of the duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this quicker with a map counting the number of values:

```
public class Compare {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the string:");
        Map<int, int> values = new HashMap<int, int>();
        for (int i=0; i<7;i++) {
          value = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
          if (!values.contains(value)) {
              values.put(value, 1);
          } else {
              values.put(value, values.get(value) + 1);
          }
        }
        for (int value : values.keySet()) {
          if (values.get(value) == 1) {
            System.out.println(value);
          }
        }
     }       
}
```